# What is the borderline between the opengraph protocol and facebook's opengraph?

Tags: facebook-opengraph

I have read a little bit about [OpenGraph](http://ogp.me/) and [Facebook's OpenGraph](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/concepts/opengraph/) API but I am unsure if I understood the concepts well enough to draw a border which separates them.

If I understood correctly, the opengrahp protocol basically provides some standard notations (set of properties and datatypes) to richly describe objects (including webpages).

At Facebook's Open Graph page, they basically add context to the feed/wall activities, by defining activities as: User + Action + Object.

Is Facebook's Open Graph just an "extension" (an additional namespace) on the top of open graph primitives but defining a vocabulary of actions and object? Or is it an implementation?

Is the concept of activity as User + Action + Object also part of facebook namespace?

I decided to put a bounty to this question, so I am expecting a very complete answer =D

Answer (score 0):

I have some experience using Facebook's Open Graph. If you have a web site and someone shares/likes your site on Facebook, your open graph tags will be picked up and Facebook will use its title, description, image, etc. Facebook's Open Graph is for Applications. For instance, if you have an app that allows people to show recipes and tell you when they cook food, the 'Action' (verb) would be "Cook". The object would be the "Recipe" which you would change to whatever food they made using your app.

An example would be: "Thomas cooked chicken using App Name"

I believe Facebook's Open Graph is just an extension but you have to follow their markup for your information to be correct and show properly.

I'm not sure if I answered your question or not but I hope you figure it out.

Comment: It is still not much clear for me =D I can see that you can add open graph tags to your page and richly describe the page or resources, and they can be targeted as "objects" in facebook when an activity is being published. And I can see as well that facebook allows an application to create objects and verbs under opengraph, but by doing that is it generating an open graph schema for the user? Is there a default facebook open graph schema with facebook verbs such as like, post, etc? Is the activity concept User + Action + Object  part of that facebook schema?